# How to conditionally include manifest options when making a JAR in ANT

Tags: class, ant, jar, manifest, program-entry-point

I am using ANT to manage multiple projects.  I have a build-common.xml script that individual projects include.  Some projects are libraries, others are programs.  For the programs, I would like to include

```
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
</manifest>
```

in the `<jar>` tag.  For libraries, I would like to have an empty jar tag as follows.

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile" description="generate a jar">
    <mkdir dir="${build}/jar" />
    <property name="jarfile" value="${jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" />
    <jar jarfile="${jarfile}" basedir="${classes}">
    </jar>
</target>
```

Is there a way I can include the manifest attribute Main-Class only if the property main.class is defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **conditional targets**:

```
<target name="jar-mkdir" depends="compile" description="generate a jar">
  <mkdir dir="${build}/jar" />
  <property name="jarfile" value="${jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" />
</target>

<target name="jar-main" depends="compile" description="generate a jar" if="main.class">
  <jar jarfile="${jarfile}" basedir="${classes}">
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>

<target name="jar-nomain" depends="compile" description="generate a jar" unless="main.class">
  <jar jarfile="${jarfile}" basedir="${classes}">
  </jar>
</target>


<target name="jar" depends="compile, jar-mkdir, jar-main, jar-nomain" description="generate a jar">
</target>
```

This will run `jar-main` (and add the manifest) only when main.class is present. When it is not present `jar-nomain` will run.

Comment: Great!  This makes a lot of sense.  I knew some of the components, but I didn't know how to put it all together.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I don't post many questions on stackoverflow.  I tried to vote you up but I don't have enough reputation (I think I lost my old account before stackoverflow supported openid)...